# R multicore ultra-high dimensional univariate analysis

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I have a data frame consisting of 1M covariates where I would like to regress every single one, independently on a specific column of the data frame using R, but in a multi core fashion. By univariate analysis I mean either a binomial regression or a wilcoxon test.

my current code is this

```
library(MASS)
library(doParallel)
tt=dat.at.fil
nm.cores = detectCores() - 1
cl=makeCluster(nm.cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
x <- foreach(cnt=1:nrow(tt),.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
whol.dat = data.frame(log10(t(tt)[,cnt]), y=factor(my.y))
deviance(glm(y~., data = whol.dat[-which(whol.dat[,1] == -Inf),], family = "binomial"))
}
```

or

```
library(MASS)
library(doParallel)
tt=dat.at.fil
nm.cores = detectCores() - 1
cl=makeCluster(nm.cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
x <- foreach(cnt=1:nrow(tt),.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
whol.dat = data.frame(t(tt)[,cnt], y=factor(my.y))
wilcoxon.test(y~., data = whol.dat))
     }
```

I wonder how I can improve it to be even more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of how the step of breaking your problem into pieces can really affect the benefits of parallel computation. I left out some pieces of your code (e.g. log transformation of covariates and elimination of missing values) which are not essential to the problem. I think you want to avoid transposing the entire matrix on every call -- just do that once at the top of your script. AFAIK R stores data in column major order, so just avoiding that step by working on the columns might already save you a bit of time.

In the first trial I first ran a version in serial to see just how much improvement there was. This is on an AMD Phenom 9850 Quad core at 2.5 GHz with 8 GB of RAM (so old).

```
library(doParallel)
library(iterators)
#make covariate data
N = 100
P = 100000 # number of predictors
tt = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(N*P),nrow=N,ncol=P))
my.y = rbinom(N,p=0.5,size=1)
y = factor(my.y)

# How fast to do it serially?
system.time(x1 <- foreach(cc = iter(tt, by='col'),.combine=c) %do% {
  deviance(glm(y~cc, family = "binomial"))
}) # elapsed 718 s

nm.cores = detectCores() - 1
cl=makeCluster(nm.cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# send entire dataframe to each worker, pull out the desired column
system.time(x2 <- foreach(cnt=1:ncol(tt),.combine=c) %dopar% {
  whol.dat = data.frame(tt[,cnt], y=factor(my.y))
  deviance(glm(y~., data = whol.dat, family = "binomial"))
}) # elapsed 276 s, so 3 x faster

all.equal(x1,x2) # TRUE, just checkin' ...
```

My first thought was that sending the entire matrix to each worker each time might carry some overhead, so I rewrote the `foreach()` to use `iter()` to just send each column to the worker:

```
system.time(x3 <- foreach(cc = iter(tt, by='col'),.combine=c) %dopar% {
  deviance(glm(y~cc, family = "binomial"))
}) # not much faster, 248s
```

And that does speed it up some, but not much. I'd not used iterators before, so while reading the foreach vignette I came across a custom iterator `iblkcol()` that breaks the data.frame into chunks, and sends each chunk to save on the overhead of dispatching data to and getting it back from the workers. The code for that [is hidden away on Github](https://github.com/cran/foreach/blob/master/inst/doc/foreach.R) (see lines 199-218).

```
## from vignette on foreach:
## use iblkcol() instead of iter in loop to send blocks of columns instead of one at a time
system.time(x4 <- foreach(cc = iblkcol(tt, chunks = nm.cores),.combine=c,.packages='foreach') %dopar% {
  foreach(x = 1:col(cc),.combine=c) %do% {
    deviance(glm(y~cc[,x], family = "binomial"))
  }
}) # 193 s!
```

And that's a substantial improvement over sending each column one at a time. I think there could be some additional speedups by tweaking the call to glm() to take advantage of the fact that most of the model frame is reused from one call to the next. The same thing ought to work with the call to wilcoxon().

Comment: can you update your answer how to make it when there is blocking factor, e.g glm(y~cc[,x] | team + week, family = "binomial") something like this. I am asking because at every iteration, we need to hold "week" and "team" information as well.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by blocking factor, but if the factors team and week are constant across columns of your big dataframe, just use them in the call to glm(), like glm(y~cc[,x] * team + week, family=binomial)